# When is making a subtitle file for a commercial movie legal?

Tags: copyright, translation

For example, on OpenSubtitles, a website which offers 3.5 million subtitles we can read [Disclaimer](http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/disclaimer):

> These files are NOT illegal warez downloads, we only offer files that we believe we are free to redistribute.

Therefore when does creating/making open subtitles for commercial movies/TV and publishing it become illegal in [First World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_World) countries?

Does it depend on the production company (if they agree or their license), format of the file (like [IDX+SUB](http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/faq#formats)) or something else?

Comment: Initially posted at [Open Source](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1663/407), but it's off-topic there.

Comment: What about fair use being to provide accessibility (closed captioning) for those with impaired heading? for arbitrary content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making and sharing and using subtitles for movies is not legal. It is copyright infringement. *I paint this statement with a very broad brush*.

The movies are copyrighted (they are original and fixed in tangible form). ([17 U.S. Code § 102(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/102))

[17 U.S. Code § 106(2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/106)) provides that the owner of copyright has the exclusive rights to prepare and to authorize to preparation of **derivative works** based upon the copyrighted work.

[17 U.S. Code § 101](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/101) defines **derivative work** as

> a work **based upon** one or more preexisting works, such as a
> **translation**, musical arrangement, dramatization, fictionalization,
> motion picture version, sound recording, art reproduction, abridgment,
> condensation, or any other form in which a work may be recast,
> transformed, or adapted....

So we have established that the copyright holder has exclusive rights to authorize translations, but this exclusive right is limited by fair use. [17 U.S. Code § 107](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/107) provides some examples of fair use:

> criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching (including multiple
> copies for classroom use), scholarship, or research

**If these subtitle files are not used for a fair use purpose (the examples cited are examples only, not an exhaustive list) then translation is infringement.**

If the files **are** used for one of the fair use purposes then § 107 also gives us the factors to determine whether that particular use is fair use:

> (1) the purpose and character of the use, including whether such use
> is of a commercial nature or is for nonprofit educational purposes;
>
> (2) the nature of the copyrighted work;
>
> (3) the amount and substantiality of the portion used in relation to
> the copyrighted work as a whole; and
>
> (4) the effect of the use upon the potential market for or value of
> the copyrighted work.

Comment: For the purpose of (3), is "the copyrighted work as a whole" the movie or the original script?

Comment: With subtitle files it could be either perhaps. The spoken words (what becomes subtitles) are a part of the movie as a whole. The script might be its own work. I suppose it depends on how the subtitles are generated - ie what they are a copy of. But keep in mind that we don't even get to (3) unless the use is one of the enumerated fair use categories (or similar categories as a court may determine).

Comment: Is _transcription_ different to _translation_, or the same rule applies?

Comment: @kenorb translation is a derivative work, so it's prohibited.

Comment: _Translation_ is translating from one language into another, however _transcription_ is representation of the same language but in written form (e.g. English subtitles to English-spoken movie). Above cite doesn't mention _transcription_.

Comment: @kenorb I see what you're asking. It seems to me that transcription is even more likely to infringe than translation because it's a literal, word for word, copy of the original. As opposed to a translation which arguably requires some interpretation and original thought.

Comment: "*f these subtitle files are not used for one of these purposes then the creation, sharing, using, and translation is not fair use, it is infringement. * This is a common misconception, bu badly mistaken. The purposes listed in the 1st part of 17 USC 1097 are **examples** not conditions. It is the stuatory factors and te analysis under them that control whether a use i8s a fair use. Courts have found fair use where the purpose is not any of  "*criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching (including multiple copies for classroom use), scholarship, or research*". This is a question of its own

Comment: @DavidSiegel edited